# airflow check status of previous tasks

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG with branching, so exist the case that all tasks previous to `dummyjoin` task has the skipped status.

The `dummyjoin` trigger the subsequent tasks with the `all_done` rule.

So I'm trying to find one rule that let me trigger the end of the DAG if all previous tasks for `dummyjoin` has been skipped, but I can't find it.

Or in other words, trigger the subsequent tasks only if at least one task has the `success` status.

The `one_success` from airflow trigger rule don't suit my requirement, because that rule trigger the next task AS SOON as one of the previous task has this status, and I want to wait to all previous tasks finish and then if there is one task with `success` status, trigger the next tasks, else end.

The tasks follow the next composition:

```
... >> [taskA, taskB, taskC, ..., taskN] >> dummyjoin >> subsequent_tasks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `none_failed`?

From the documentation:

> none_failed: all parents have not failed (failed or upstream_failed) i.e. all parents have succeeded or been skipped

If that does not work for you (if you need at least one of the tasks to have succeeded), I guess the only way is to add a second dummyjoin task in parallel to your first dummyjoin like so:

```
... >> [taskA, taskB, taskC, ..., taskN] >> [dummyjoin1, dummyjoin2] >> subsequent_tasks
```

and set the trigger_rule for `dummyjoin1` to `none_failed` and the trigger_rule for `dummyjoin2` to `one_success`